# C- Measuring numbers of read writes called by a function

Tags: c

I want to check number of read writes made by a function.lets say my c program has two functions which are called separately from main() , both function provides some read write activity (Or system calls for IO operations). Now i want to make comparative analysis of both functions in terms of IO.

Please help , Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Write wrappers around IO functions, such that you increment a counter when the wrapper is called, e.g.:

```
void custom_read(int *counter) {
  *counter++;
  real_read();
}

/* ... */

int read_counter = 0;
custom_read(&read_counter);
custom_read(&read_counter);
...
custom_read(&read_counter);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially a mixture of *code coverage analysis*, *call graph tracing* and *profiling*.

The tools to use depend strongly on the OS, but the general idea is the same:

You use a *call graph* generator to find all the code paths that trigger the function you want to analyze. Next you use a profiler, to count the invocations of functions by another function (you can for example filter all the events where a function `foo` calls function `bar`). Now you can use the *code coverage* analysis to see the distribution of CPU cycles spent on the areas of the code.

Comment: Thanks, 
To be more specific i am using ubuntu-12.04.
So , should i use a profiler tool which can detect count of IO events made by particular function  ?

Comment: In that case I suggest to utilize the fact, that you can control gdb from another process. I'd use that to implement a small script, that loads the binary in gdb, sets breakpoints on the desired functions to be traced, run the program, and everytime it reached a breakpoint let gdb dump a backtrace and continue the program. There's a nice Python module to invoke and control GDB: http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html#Python

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to wrap the read and write functions, and replace the read and write functions with the wrappers in your target program.